# PostgreSQL and the Linux Kernel

Tags: postgresql

I have a Postgres 9.5 to serve a OpenStreetMap database (about 500GB of data)

I'm a realy newbie to configure the server and just follow these instructions: http://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/

But... after reading the araqnid's answer [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/284799/postgres-disk-io-very-high-what-can-i-do-to-reduce-it-immediately?newreg=1d2c619be9154a54b1bb671e2b99216f) I need to know if changing `kernel.shmmax` is realy important.

My server have 8 cores, a SATA HDD and 64 GB of RAM and running  PostgreSQL + Tomcat + Geoserver and sometimes the map generation is painful (it is fine after all image caches generated).

Using `htop` I can see the cores and the memory running loose and a very high disk I/O.

what is the correct value for the `kernel.shmmax` and what more can I change?

Comment: Install netdata, look at the metrics and you should find the cause of your slows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TL;DR: increasing kernel.shmmax is no longer necessary.

PostgreSQL used to need a large `kernel.shmmax` before version 9.3, as its "shared buffers" were allocated using SysV shared memory.

It **used to** have this recommendation:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/kernel-resources.html
which is now **obsolete** ([9.2 has been EOL'ed in 2017](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)).

> The most important shared memory parameter is SHMMAX, the maximum
>   size, in bytes, of a shared memory segment. If you get an error
>   message from shmget like "Invalid argument", it is likely that this
>   limit has been exceeded. The size of the required shared memory
>   segment varies depending on several PostgreSQL configuration
>   parameters, as shown in Table 17-2. (Any error message you might get
>   will include the exact size of the failed allocation request.) You
>   can, as a temporary solution, lower some of those settings to avoid
>   the failure. While it is possible to get PostgreSQL to run with SHMMAX
>   as small as 2 MB, you need considerably more for acceptable
>   performance. Desirable settings are in the hundreds of megabytes to a
>   few gigabytes.

---

But that's not the version you're using.
For 9.5,  see the documentation at
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/kernel-resources.html :

> PostgreSQL requires a few bytes of System V shared memory (typically
>   48 bytes, on 64-bit platforms) for each copy of the server. On most
>   modern operating systems, this amount can easily be allocated.

Comment: Wow, doesn't know about it. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You should change your `kernel.shmmax` according `shared_buffers` parameter configured in your `postgresql.conf`. If `kernel.shmmax` would be lesser then configured in postgresql config, it just couldn't start.

Comment: Well ... my server have started. So is it all ok? No tunning needed here?

Comment: @MagnoC, if PostgreSQL after tuning start without problem, so there is no need to tune `shmmax` in sysctl.

Comment: What about this: https://gist.github.com/malkitsingh/737ea34abec5b079a84dd39e3b0dc2d2 ( Item 2 ) ?